# Why MatchAgain method of TPerlRegEx doesn't works

Tags: regex, delphi

I want to extract `SAAM` and `SAAMI` from the following text by using `RegEX`(I'm coding in Delphi XE4 and XE5) :

```
RegEx = 'Name:\s?(.*),Family:\s?(.*)';
```

For example I've this text :

```
Name: SAAM
Family: SAAMI
```

I wrote this code, and use the `MatchAgain` method of `TPerlRegEx` for matching two regex (`'Name:\s?(.*)'` And `'Family:\s?(.*)'`) .

```
...
var
  RX: TPerlRegEx;
const
  RegEx = 'Name:\s?(.*),Family:\s?(.*)';
begin
  RX := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    RX.RegEx := RegEx;
    RX.Subject := mmo1.Text;// The mmo1.text value is "Name: SAAM and Family: SAAMI"
    if RX.Match then
    begin
      repeat
        ShowMessage('Name is :' + RX.Groups[1]);
        ShowMessage('Family is :' + RX.Groups[2]);
      until not RX.MatchAgain;
    end;
  finally
    RX.Free;
  end;
...
```

Why this code doesn't works ??

Comment: define [`doesn't work`](http://regex101.com/r/nA9aE7), do you get an error ? No matches ? Please be precise.

Comment: @HamZa I can't get any matches !

Comment: Ok logically speaking, what do you see after `SAAM` ? Do you see a newline or a comma `,` ? Now take a look at your expression and tell me what you see. That's your hint.

Comment: @HamZa I see newline(maybe 100 lines !), But i put comma for splitting two expression .

Comment: Here's your second hint `comma != newline(s)`

Comment: @HamZa :| I know this, for newline i should use `\r`. In Delphi i use this style `'Name:\s?(.*),Family:\s?(.*)'` instead of using two expression (for example i use  instead of `('Name:\s?(.*)'` And `'Family:\s?(.*)'`).

Comment: If that's what you want, you want to use "or" in regex. I've seen a lot of regex flavors but I've not seen one using a comma `,` to express an `or` statement. Use `|` instead of `,`.

Comment: Please See this link [VirusTotal Scanner 0.1](https://www.underground.org.mx/index.php?topic=29199.0). There is a good example.

Comment: @HamZa +1: tanks for your advice i use `|` instead of `,` and it works noW .

Comment: That example you provided is crap, it seems like he's parsing JSON with regex and now he has confused you. I would advice you to avoid such shabby websites about hacking. Generally they teach you crap and sometimes they even try to infect you. If you're into security try to check [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/183/25859) for a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change my code to this, and it works (Almost :-) ) correctly for me.

Example text :

```
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
Name: SAAM
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
Family: SAAMI
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
  Junk text :-)
```

New code :

```
var
  RX: TPerlRegEx;
  i: Integer;
const
  RegEx = 'Name:\s?(.*)|Family:\s?(.*)';
begin
  i := 1;
  RX := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    RX.RegEx := RegEx;
    RX.Subject := mmo1.Text;
    if RX.Match then
    begin
      repeat
        case i of
          1:
            ShowMessage('Name is: ' + RX.Groups[i]);
          2:
            ShowMessage('Family is: ' + RX.Groups[i]);
        end;

        Inc(i);
      until not RX.MatchAgain;
    end;
  finally
    RX.Free;
  end;
```

And result :

```
Name is: SAAM
Family is: SAAMI
```